# How does shifting the multiplier and multiplicand, result in the product of the two?

Tags: assembly, mips

Hello there I am really confused about the shifting part, I understand that a left shift by N results in a value of 2^N, but how is shifting the multiplier left and the multiplicand right, getting the product of the two??

Here's the code that computes the product of two numbers entered from the console:

```
.data

string1: .asciiz "Enter multiplier : "
string2: .asciiz "\nEnter multiplicand : "

.text

li $s0, -1

la $a0, string1
li $v0, 4
syscall

li $v0, 5
syscall

move $a0, $v0
bltzal $a0, Negate
move $t0, $v0

la $a0, string2
li $v0, 4
syscall

li $v0, 5
syscall

move $a0, $v0
bltzal $a0, Negate
move $t1, $v0



li $t2, 1
li $t3, 0

loop:

andi $t5, $t1, 1

bnez $t5, addPartial

shift:
sll $t0,$t0,1
srl $t1,$t1,1
bgtz $t1, loop


done:

beqz $s0, negative_answer
bgtz $s0, positive_answer
bltz $s0, positive_values

Negate:

addiu $s0, $s0, 1
negu $v0, $a0
jr $ra

addPartial:
addu $t3, $t3, $t0
j shift

positive_answer:
move $a0, $t3
li $v0, 1
syscall

li $v0, 10
syscall

negative_answer:

negu $t3, $t3
move $a0, $t3
li $v0, 1
syscall

li $v0, 10
syscall


positive_values:
move $a0, $t3
li $v0, 1
syscall

li $v0, 10
syscall
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I not familiar with the MIPS instruction set. Also the lack of commends makes it so that my answer might not as to the point as it could be, but anyway here it goes.

Lets say you want to multiply 7 and 11, or 0111b and 1011b. This can be rewritten as;

1*1011 + 10*1011 + 100*1011 + 0000*1011 = 1*1011 + 1*10110 + 1*1011000 + 0*10110000

So if with

```
shift right the multiplicand
collect the bit pushed off
add the multiplier to the answer if this bit is 1
shift left the multiplier
repeat until finished
```

or

```
check LO bit of multiplicand
add the multiplier to the answer if this bit is 1
shift left the multiplier
shift right the multiplicand
repeat until finished
```

you can calculate the answer of an arbitrarily large multiplication.

I hope this answers your question.